# How to use Font Awesome from webjars.org with JSF

Tags: css, jsf, maven, font-awesome, webjars

I am trying to use [Font Awesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/) icons with my JSF application. I have had some success by following the [getting started instructions](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/get-started/) and adding the following to my view's `<h:head>` section:

```
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css"
      rel="stylesheet" />
```

This gives me a nice home icon when I use the `icon-home` class:

[image]

However, I don't want to be dependent on the bootstrap server to provide the Font Awesome resources, so I am trying to bundle these with my war, and configure my views to use the bundled resources.

I am using the [pre-made JAR](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.webjars/font-awesome/3.2.1) created by the [webjars](http://www.webjars.org/) project. My pom has the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
    <artifactId>font-awesome</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

This places the JAR in my WAR's WEB-INF/lib directory. The relevent parts of the JAR's structure are:

```
META-INF
  - MANIFEST.MF
  + maven
  - resources
    - webjars
      - font-awesome
        - 3.2.1
          - css
            - font-awesome.css
            - *other css files*
          - font
            - *font files*
```

I have tried the following to include the icons in my project:

```
<h:outputStylesheet library="webjars" 
                    name="font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css"  />
```

However, this renders the previously working home icon as:

[image]

And my browser (Chrome) shows the following errors in the console (domain/port/context-root changed to protect the innocent ;):

```
GET http://DOMAIN:PORT/CONTEXT-ROOT/javax.faces.resource/font-awesome/3.2.1/font/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=3.2.1 404 (Not Found) 
GET http://DOMAIN:PORT/CONTEXT-ROOT/javax.faces.resource/font-awesome/3.2.1/font/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=3.2.1 404 (Not Found) 
GET http://DOMAIN:PORT/CONTEXT-ROOT/javax.faces.resource/font-awesome/3.2.1/font/fontawesome-webfont.svg 404 (Not Found)
```

So it looks like although the css file is resolved properly, the files which contain the fonts that the css file refers to cannot be found. I have checked those references in the css file and they are:

```
src: url('../font/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=3.2.1');
src: url('../font/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=3.2.1') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../font/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=3.2.1') format('woff'), url('../font/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=3.2.1') format('truetype'), url('../font/fontawesome-webfont.svg#fontawesomeregular?v=3.2.1') format('svg');
```

Those paths are relative to the css resource, so I thought JSF should have no problem finding it. Now I'm not sure what to do.

Any pointers would be great! Cheers.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The JSF mapping and library name is missing in those URLs. If you've mapped your `FacesServlet` on `*.xhtml`, then those URLs should actually have been:

```
GET http://DOMAIN:PORT/CONTEXT-ROOT/javax.faces.resource/font-awesome/3.2.1/font/fontawesome-webfont.woff.xhtml?ln=webjars&v=3.2.1
GET http://DOMAIN:PORT/CONTEXT-ROOT/javax.faces.resource/font-awesome/3.2.1/font/fontawesome-webfont.ttf.xhtml?ln=webjars&v=3.2.1
GET http://DOMAIN:PORT/CONTEXT-ROOT/javax.faces.resource/font-awesome/3.2.1/font/fontawesome-webfont.svg.xhtml?ln=webjars
```

Essentially, you should be using `#{resource}` in CSS file to print the proper JSF resource URL:

```
src: url("#{resource['webjars:font-awesome/3.2.1/font/fontawesome-webfont.eot']}&v=3.2.1");
src: url("#{resource['webjars:font-awesome/3.2.1/font/fontawesome-webfont.eot']}&#iefix&v=3.2.1");
```

However, as the source code is actually outside your control (you can't edit it), then there's no other way to manage the resource handling yourself. The JSF utility library [OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org) provides the [`UnmappedResourceHandler`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/resourcehandlers/UnmappedResourceHandler) out the box for the exact purpose. With the following steps your problem should be solved:

1. Install OmniFaces, it's available on Maven as well.

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.omnifaces</groupId>
       <artifactId>omnifaces</artifactId>
       <version><!-- Check omnifaces.org for current version. --></version>
   </dependency>
   ```
2. Register `UnmappedResourceHandler` in `faces-config.xml` as follows:

   ```
   <application>
       <resource-handler>org.omnifaces.resourcehandler.UnmappedResourceHandler</resource-handler>
   </application>
   ```
3. Add `/javax.faces.resource/*` to `FacesServlet` mapping, assuming that the servlet name is `facesServlet` and you've already a mapping on `*.xhtml`:

   ```
   <servlet-mapping>
       <servlet-name>facesServlet</servlet-name>
       <url-pattern>/javax.faces.resource/*</url-pattern>
       <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
   ```
4. Move the `<h:outputStylesheet>` library name to into the resource name.

   ```
   <h:outputStylesheet name="webjars/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css" />
   ```
5. Profit.

Comment: Not sure if its appropriate to put this here but, this solution works fine but  ends up breaking <ace:dataExporter/> (which, I assume, would also break <p:dataExporter/>.  I'm guessing because these rely on unmapped resources to export files for download?  I'm getting stuff like this in the logs: Warning: JSF1091: No mime type could be found for file s01a3dc15-c480-4769-a71a-bc08f191416f.

Comment: @wsaxton: Which OmniFaces version? There's since 1.8 a hack in place to recognize PF dynamic resources so it could delegate accordingly.

Comment: I'm using 1.8.  Is there another way to do this then?  (BTW, I did ask this question in another post if you want to reply there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28637732/how-can-i-integrate-font-awesome-with-jsf-difficulties-with-omnifaces-solution)

Comment: @balusc: Answer could be simplified see my answer below. Maybe you can edit this one

Comment: If you wonder, why this does not work with 5.8.1 version of font awesome I tell you: the path inside the jar is different now. You have to use "webjars/font-awesome/5.8.1/css/fontawesome.css" as path. @BalusC - you answered almost all questions I ask myself about JSF :) Thanks a lot.

Comment: hmm. Actually I have a problem with 5.8.1 version. If I try to include "webjars/font-awesome/5.8.1/css/all.min.css", then the fonts cannot be found. So for example I get this error: "GET http://xxxx/yyy/webfonts/fa-solid-900.woff net::ERR_ABORTED 404". @BalusC do you have any idea, how to fix this without changing the css inside the jar?

Comment: @BalusC I figured out. I have to include "webjars/font-awesome/5.8.1/css/all-jsf.css" then it works. Cool that the font awesome developer think on JSF people :)

Answer (score 18):

The answer above is kind of made obsolete. Since some releases ago, the webjar version of font-awesome includes a specific jsf-ified version of the css so there is nothing to configure. Add the jar to your project, either via [maven](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.webjars/font-awesome/4.6.3)

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
   <artifactId>font-awesome</artifactId>
   <version>4.6.3</version>
</dependency>
```

or directly and it just works. Just make sure you include the correct css

```
<h:outputStylesheet library="webjars" name="font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome-jsf.css" />
```

Note the -jsf in the name!!! This way you can always have the latest version in your application and do not depend on PF releasing something new

Comment: There were some changes in version 5.x.x of awesome fonts, and <h:outputStylesheet library="webjars" name="font-awesome/5.9.0/css/all-jsf.css" /> is working for me.

Answer (score 7):

In addition to BalusC answer, it's a good idea to add the following `mime-mapping`s to the `web.xml`

```
<!-- web fonts -->
<mime-mapping>
    <extension>eot</extension>
    <mime-type>application/vnd.ms-fontobject</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
<mime-mapping>
    <extension>otf</extension>
    <mime-type>font/opentype</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
<mime-mapping>
    <extension>ttf</extension>
    <mime-type>application/x-font-ttf</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
<mime-mapping>
    <extension>woff</extension>
    <mime-type>application/x-font-woff</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
<mime-mapping>
    <extension>woff2</extension>
    <mime-type>application/x-font-woff2</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
<mime-mapping>
    <extension>svg</extension>
    <mime-type>image/svg+xml</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
<mime-mapping>
    <extension>ico</extension>
    <mime-type>image/x-icon</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
```

Answer (score 3):

In addition to ***BalusC*** and ***Hatem Alimam*** answers, this could be useful too by adding:

```
<context-param>
   <param-name>primefaces.FONT_AWESOME</param-name>
   <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

According to this [link](http://javahow.net/questions/10152012/primefaces-icons/10152681)

Comment: yes, primefaces [now supports fontawesome](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/misc/fa.xhtml) out of the box since version 5.2. This is the approach I now use.

Comment: But in this approach you'll always behind the most recent font-awesome versions. Adding your own and using it in my answer guarantees the latest

Answer (score 2):

For primefaces 6.2 also this worked fine for me

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>font-awesome</artifactId>
        <version>5.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

and in xhtml file:

```
<h:outputScript library="webjars" name="font-awesome/5.5.0/js/all.js"/>
```

be aware, that you have to change the usage from 4 to 5, for example `fa fa-plus` to `fas fa-plus`, based on web page - https://fontawesome.com/icons/plus?style=solid

Comment: Or use the css variant: `<h:outputStylesheet library="webjars" name="font-awesome/5.5.0/css/all-jsf.css" />`