# Font-awesome icons are shown as squares

Tags: css, jsf, font-awesome

I've tried to use icons from [font-awesome](http://fontawesome.io/) and from [social-buttons](http://lipis.github.io/bootstrap-social/) libraries, but they are shown as squares:

[image: No icons]

**Code:**

```
<a class="btn btn-social-icon btn-google-plus"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a>
<a class="btn btn-social-icon btn-vk"><i class="fa fa-vk"></i></a>
<a class="btn btn-social-icon btn-twitter"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
<a class="btn btn-social-icon btn-facebook"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
```

**Output .xhtml file contains:**

```
<head>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/WebAcademy/javax.faces.resource/theme.css.xhtml?ln=primefaces-aristo">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/WebAcademy/javax.faces.resource/bootstrap-3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css.xhtml?ln=styles">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/WebAcademy/javax.faces.resource/font-awesome-4.1.0/css/font-awesome.css.xhtml?ln=styles">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/WebAcademy/javax.faces.resource/bootstrap-social-gh-pages/bootstrap-social.css.xhtml?ln=styles">
</head>
```

So, I suppose, css libs are imported.

Also I have in my *web.xml* MIME-mappings:

```
<mime-mapping>
    <extension>eot</extension>
    <mime-type>application/vnd.ms-fontobject</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
<mime-mapping>
    <extension>otf</extension>
    <mime-type>font/opentype</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
<mime-mapping>
    <extension>ttf</extension>
    <mime-type>application/x-font-ttf</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
<mime-mapping>
    <extension>woff</extension>
    <mime-type>application/x-font-woff</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
<mime-mapping>
    <extension>svg</extension>
    <mime-type>image/svg+xml</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
```

Any ideas why icons are shown as empty squares?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @BalusC, Thanks for response. After launching Console, I investigated [such problem](http://i.gyazo.com/d51564a5a1c0f8fed6dbefdc7064ad18.png).

Comment: Finally, I resolved it!

**[This helped](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18894588/668148)**.