# How can I integrate Font Awesome 4.3.0 with JSF?

Tags: jsf-2, font-awesome

I've already tried this method:

[How to use Font Awesome from webjars.org with JSF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18891768/how-to-use-font-awesome-from-webjars-org-with-jsf)

It actually works great.  The problem is that configuring the omnifaces UnmappedResourceHandler as a resource handler breaks one of my other JSF library components:

```
faces-config.xml:

<application>
    <resource-handler>org.omnifaces.resourcehandler.UnmappedResourceHandler</resource-handler>
</application>
```

When I try to use an **ace:dataExporter** (which I think is the same as a **p:dataExporter**)

```
webpage.xhtml: 

<ace:dataExporter target="dataTable" fileName="data" type="csv"/>
```

Nothing gets exported and I get the following in my glassfish logs:

```
Warning: JSF1091: No mime type could be found for file s01a3dc15-c480-4769-a71a-bc08f191416f.  To resolve this, add a mime-type mapping to the applications web.xml.
Warning: JSF1091: No mime type could be found for file 71a-bc08f191416f.  To resolve this, add a mime-type mapping to the applications web.xml.
```

I'm open to any other suggestions to packaging font-awesome into my web application (I can't use the CDN version).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the latest webjars font-awesome  version, there is nothing to configure. Add the jar to your project, either via maven or directly and it just works.  Just make sure you include the correct css

```
<h:outputStylesheet library="webjars" name="font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome-jsf.css" />
```