# How to use 3rd party CSS libraries such as Font Awesome with JSF? Browser can't find font files referenced in the CSS file

Tags: css, jsf, font-awesome

I'm trying to integrate [Font Awesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/) in JSF.

```
<h:outputStylesheet library="font-awesome" name="css/font-awesome.min.css" />
```

But the browser can't find the font files. They appear as empty squares:

[image]

I expected them to look like below:

[image]

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: what did YOU investigate?

Comment: Read http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info --> "Any faces messages or warnings/errors/exceptions in browser console or server logs?" and update your question accordingly. Surely the webbrowser must have given clues.

Comment: thank's you are right sir, there is many errors : i can't locate many files like "fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.2.0"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I integrate Font Awesome 4.3.0 with JSF?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28637732/how-can-i-integrate-font-awesome-4-3-0-with-jsf)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The Font Awesome CSS file is by default referencing those font files via a relative path `../` like below:

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.3.0');
  src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=4.3.0') format('embedded-opentype'),
       url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.3.0') format('woff2'),
       url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.3.0') format('woff'),
       url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.3.0') format('truetype'),
       url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.3.0#fontawesomeregular') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

This will fail if the CSS file itself is requested on a different path. The JSF `<h:outputStylesheet>` will do that if you specify the `library` attribute. Moreover, the JSF will use a special `/javax.faces.resource/*` prefix pattern for those resources so that specifically the JSF resource handler will be invoked which allows customization freedom. Detail can be found in [What is the JSF resource library for and how should it be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11988415/what-is-the-jsf-resource-library-for-and-how-should-it-be-used)

Provided a folder structure like below,

```
WebContent
 |-- resources
 |    `-- font-awesome
 |         |-- css
 |         |    |-- font-awesome.css
 |         |    `-- font-awesome.min.css
 |         `-- fonts
 |              |-- fontawesome-webfont.eot
 |              |-- fontawesome-webfont.svg
 |              |-- fontawesome-webfont.ttf
 |              |-- fontawesome-webfont.woff
 |              `-- fontawesome-webfont.woff2
 :
```

And the Font Awesome CSS being included as below:

```
<h:outputStylesheet library="font-awesome" name="css/font-awesome.min.css" />
```

Then you need to edit the CSS file as below to use `#{resource}` mapping in EL to reference the font files in `/resources` folder with the appropriate library and resource name (and as library name ends up as a query string parameter already, you also need to replace `?` by `&`, this is not necessary if you don't use a library name).

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  src: url("#{resource['font-awesome:fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot']}&v=4.3.0");
  src: url("#{resource['font-awesome:fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot']}&#iefix&v=4.3.0") format('embedded-opentype'),
       url("#{resource['font-awesome:fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2']}&v=4.3.0") format('woff2'),
       url("#{resource['font-awesome:fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff']}&v=4.3.0") format('woff'),
       url("#{resource['font-awesome:fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf']}&v=4.3.0") format('truetype'),
       url("#{resource['font-awesome:fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg']}&v=4.3.0#fontawesomeregular") format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

Make sure you restart the server after editing the CSS file. The presence of EL expressions in a certain CSS file is detected only once during the first time the JSF resource handler reads the CSS file and then remembered applicationwide.

In case you're seeing JSF1091 warnings in server logs for those font files like below:

> WARNING: JSF1091: No mime type could be found for file [some font file]. To resolve this, add a mime-type mapping to the applications web.xml.

Then you need to act accordingly by adding below mime mappings to `web.xml`:

```
<mime-mapping>
    <extension>eot</extension>
    <mime-type>application/vnd.ms-fontobject</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
<mime-mapping>
    <extension>otf</extension>
    <mime-type>font/opentype</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
<mime-mapping>
    <extension>svg</extension>
    <mime-type>image/svg+xml</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
<mime-mapping>
    <extension>ttf</extension>
    <mime-type>application/x-font-ttf</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
<mime-mapping>
    <extension>woff</extension>
    <mime-type>application/x-font-woff</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
<mime-mapping>
    <extension>woff2</extension>
    <mime-type>application/x-font-woff2</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
```

If you happen to use JSF utility library [OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org), an alternative to editing the CSS file with the `#{resource}` mapping, is to install the OmniFaces [`UnmappedResourceHandler`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/resourcehandlers/UnmappedResourceHandler) and reconfigure the `FacesServlet` mapping as per its documentation. You only need to make sure that you don't reference the font CSS file via `library` anymore:

```
<h:outputStylesheet name="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
```

#### See also:

- [How to use Font Awesome from webjars.org with JSF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18891768/how-to-use-font-awesome-3-2-1-from-webjars-org-with-jsf/)

Comment: Thank's it's work for me but you have to replace "?" by "&" like that :  url('http://localhost:8080/Students_manager/javax.faces.resource/fontawesome-webfont.ttf.xhtml?ln=font-awesome/fonts&v=4.2.0') format('truetype'),

Comment: Right, overlooked that bit. Fixed.

Comment: @BalusC: using the font-awesome rom webjars contains all these things. I think there even is a SO Q/A about it. Way easier to maintain

Comment: The mime mapping in web.xml worked for me  i just had to remove the tmp content in jboss7 (took more than a day to solve this o.O )

Comment: in case someone needs it, i created a regex for it:
search:
url\('\.\./(([a-zA-Z/-]+)\.([eotsvgttfwoffwoff2]{1,5}))'{0,1}([?\.&=#a-zA-Z0-9]{0,})'{1}
replace with:
url("#{resource['external:fontawesome/$2.$3']}&$4" where my directory is like wepapp/external/fontawesome .. you might need to adjust that

Comment: I am not getting any error now on console but Icons are still not shown. By the way it is now `v=4.7.0` now.

Comment: I got these warnings after installing a PF premium theme. Putting the mime-mappings into web.xml helped me.

Answer (score 4):

Also PrimeFaces 5.11 has Font Awesome out of the box

Just add this `context-param` to your `web.xml`:

```xml
<context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.FONT_AWESOME</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Then you can apply Font Awesome icons this way:

```html
<p:submenu label="Time" icon="fa fa-clock-o">
```

References:

- [Primefaces Font Awesome](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/misc/fa.xhtml)

Comment: Since your answer is a PrimeFaces specific one and this question is not PrimeFaces related, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28637732/how-can-i-integrate-font-awesome-4-3-0-with-jsf would have been a better referral. In my opinion it is weird PF duplicates all the work themselves that is already done in webjar

Answer (score 1):

I changed the path in "font-awesome.css" and work fine

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'FontAwesome';
src: url('../resources/font-awesome-4.5.0/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.5.0');
src: url('../resources/font-awesome-4.5.0/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=4.5.0') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('../resources/font-awesome-4.5.0/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.5.0') format('woff2'),
    url('../resources/font-awesome-4.5.0/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.5.0') format('woff'),
    url('../resources/font-awesome-4.5.0/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.5.0') format('truetype'),
    url('../resources/font-awesome-4.5.0/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.5.0#fontawesomeregular')
    format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
```

}

Comment: Path is dependent from FacesServlet mapping and this "solution" may therefore not apply to everyone.

Comment: Even better, use the fontawesome version from webjar. It contains all this. Way more simple to maintain

Answer (score 1):

You just need to manually include it via your pom.xml:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.webjars/font-awesome -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
    <artifactId>font-awesome</artifactId>
    <version>6.5.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Then include these two CSS stylesheets (do it in your template to load them in each page) to enable it:

```
<h:outputStylesheet library="webjars" name="font-awesome/6.5.1/css/all.min-jsf.css" />
<h:outputStylesheet library="webjars" name="font-awesome/6.5.1/css/v4-shims.min-jsf.css" />
```

Answer (score 0):

i changed the path of oet,ttf,svg,woff files in "font-awesome.min.css" file like this :

```
http://localhost:8080/Students_manager/javax.faces.resource/fontawesome-webfont.svg.xhtml?ln=font-awesome/fonts&v=4.2.0#fontawesomeregular
```

it's working fine for me but i still looking for another solution because i should have a dynamic path not a static like `"http://localhost:8080/Students_manager/..."`

Answer (score 0):

Same answer as **BalusC** with some changes. Note: I'm integrating Metronic Theme.

```
*/@font-face{font-family:'FontAwesome';
 src:url("#{resource['global:plugins/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot']}&v=4.4.0");
 src:url("#{resource['global:plugins/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot']}&#iefix&v=4.4.0") format('embedded-opentype'),
 url("#{resource['global:plugins/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2']}&v=4.4.0") format('woff2'),
 url("#{resource['global:plugins/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff']}&v=4.4.0") format('woff'),
 url("#{resource['global:plugins/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf']}&v=4.4.0") format('truetype'),
 url("#{resource['global:plugins/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg']}&v=4.4.0#fontawesomeregular") format('svg');font-weight:normal;font-style:normal}
```

same goes for `simple-line-icons.min.css`

and as BalusC said add change `web.xml` by adding the lines in his answer.

[image]

Comment: Use use the webjar fontawesome jar, no need for all these complex changes. And please state what changes there are. We should not have to do a manual compare!

Comment: no you can't use the jar, in my answer I talked about integrating a html theme (like metronic) in a JSF application. + any one who have read this question, he would read the accepted answer so no need for me to copy paste that answer, and the changes I made are pretty clear.