# JSF Facelet Stop Auto-Inject URL

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, jsf, jsf-2

I'm making a simple website with JSF, but having a little trouble.
I'm using Netbean to create new Java Web Application with JSF Framework + GlassFish Server 4.1.1
The web pages structure looks like this:
[image: Web pages structure]

Configuration file: `web.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

My web page use jQuery + Bootstrap, like this:

```
<h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="bootstrap.min.css" />
<h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="bootstrap-theme.min.css" />
<h:outputScript library="js" name="jquery.min.js" />
<h:outputScript library="js" name="bootstrap.min.js" />
```

The above code will be resolved as follow:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/sdv_testingall/javax.faces.resource/bootstrap.min.css.xhtml?ln=css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/sdv_testingall/javax.faces.resource/bootstrap-theme.min.css.xhtml?ln=css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/sdv_testingall/javax.faces.resource/jquery.min.js.xhtml?ln=js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/sdv_testingall/javax.faces.resource/bootstrap.min.js.xhtml?ln=js"></script>
```

The stylesheet and script still successfully imported, but the Bootstrap font attached with Bootstrap stylesheet is failed to import:

```
http://localhost:8080/sdv_testingall/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://localhost:8080/sdv_testingall/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://localhost:8080/sdv_testingall/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

I have looking around but still don't know how to fix this. Some idea are:

- Edit `bootstrap.min.css` to replace with correct font URL (maybe `glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2.xhtml?ln=font`), this is very bad idea!!!
- Make `http://localhost:8080/sdv_testingall/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2` (and others) to point to correct file in project system
- Make all file/folder in `resource` folder can directly access from URL (just like Apache Server), example: `/sdv_testingall/resource/css/bootstrap.min.css`, I don't want the URL has `.xhtml` postfix automatically with resource file (maybe i will not use `h:outputStylesheet` and use pure HTML code instead)

I think the last option is prefered. Anyone can help me, thanks

Comment: See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31434885/how-to-use-font-awesome-4-x-css-file-with-jsf-browser-cant-find-font-files... Same issue... (but for Font Awesome)

Comment: Of topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11988415/what-is-the-jsf-resource-library-for-and-how-should-it-be-used