# How to integrate FontAwesome 5 Pro licence with PrimeFaces?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, font-awesome

I just bought a FontAwesome 5 Pro Licence from their website (https://fontawesome.com/icons). I'm working on a JSF + PrimeFaces web app. Now I want to be able of using those icons in my project. 
I know that there's already a library that contains some icons but I need the Regular and Light versions:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>font-awesome</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

How can I integrate this version on my project?
Greetings

Comment: Using Fontawsome in JSF needs some customization. PF has done this for the one they include and the webjar fontawesome people has done this too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18891768/how-to-use-font-awesome-from-webjars-org-with-jsf The steps you need to take for a clean fontawesome like you have can be found in the 'linked' links on the right if you open the link in this comment.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use Font Awesome 4.x CSS file with JSF? Browser can't find font files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31434885/how-to-use-font-awesome-4-x-css-file-with-jsf-browser-cant-find-font-files)