# PrimeFaces icons not render on the commandButton

Tags: css, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, font-awesome

I am trying to use a font awesome icons with JSF+PrimeFaces. 
I added to my pom.xml file webjars dependency:

```
 <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
 <artifactId>font-awesome</artifactId>
```

Also I have my custom css file:

```
body{
    background-image: url("#{resource['images/loginBackground.jpg']}");
    background-size: 100%;
    font-family: 'Belleza', sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

I added css's resources to my page (.xhtml) in this way:

```
  <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="login.css"/>
    <h:outputStylesheet library="webjars" name="font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome-jsf.css"/>
```

But unfortunately when I set icon css class in commandButton component:

```
<p:commandButton icon="fa fa-sign-in" id="submit" value="Login" ajax="false"/>
```

The icon is not display on my button.

My others settings (**web.xml**):

```
  <context-param>
        <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
        <param-value>none</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <!-- MAPPING SECTION -->
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

**Libraries versions:**

- JSF 2.2
- PrimeFaces 5.1
- Font-Awesome 4.3.0-1

Comment: do the icons not render in general or not on the commandButton? Any network 404's?

Comment: No there is no 404 error all resources are loaded.

Comment: Problem can also be solved by adding `.ui-icon {
    text-indent: 0;
}`

Comment: @Kukeltje in my css file ? This don't work.

Comment: Strange, works for me…  check with your browser developer tool if there is a more specific selector that is more specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not want to use the built-in FA version like in the answer above and you still want to use it on the commandButton, add

```
.ui-icon {
    text-indent: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, my problem was a conflict with my theme and the font color. I could solve it putting this on my .css script:

```
.fa-trash {
    color:grey;
}
```

or just

```
.fa {
    color:grey;
}
```

Additionally, if you can't see fa icons at all, then you have to put this in web.xml:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.FONT_AWESOME</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Comment: Changing the color does not make it visible (unless it is grey on grey, but that would be a more generic issue). And in my opinion, using the built-in font-awesome is not the best solution since the version of fa you can use depends on the one PF provides. Using the webjar one is 'better'. Read all answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18891768/how-to-use-font-awesome-from-webjars-org-with-jsf

Comment: I was using south-street theme which is mostly green and I never thought the color could be a problem until after almost an hour trying different solutions, I could got the icon visible, changing the color.

Answer (score 0):

just add in web.xml code:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.FONT_AWESOME</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

and add your commandbutton like this:

```
<p:commandButton icon="fa fa-fw fa-pencil" value="Update" />
```

take a look in www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/misc/fa.xhtml

Comment: Not the best suggestion: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/4778 Using the webjar as OP does is the more future proof approach

Answer (score 0):

you should download primeicons project and add it to your project.
primeicons project : https://github.com/primefaces/primeicons .

then add this link into your page:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="primeicons-master/primeicons.css" />
```

so primefaces icons will be loaded.

Answer (score -3):

First resources file css not rendered (#{var} is stil #{var) in JSF ?, 
 
You can use 
1. Use global path 
background-image: url("../resource/images/loginBackground.jpg"); 
in css file or evrywhere 
2. 
 
Overide css primefaces style in you jsf page.
url("#{resource['images/loginBackground.jpg']}");
3.
Change in library :)

Where exsist other ways ?