# integrate bootstrap webjars into jsf in eclipse

Tags: maven, twitter-bootstrap-3, jsf-2.2, m2eclipse

hy, i am developing webapp in jsf, maven with eclipse and want to integrate bootsrap webjars into project. but found error of RES_NOT_FOUND.I am researching to fix it from many days but did found any solution. i read all solutions available in this site.Plz guide me.[image] Here is my project details .

and here is output of index.xhml file

[image]

my pom.xml

```
   <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0  http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>Com.Zed</groupId>
<artifactId>EverGreen</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>EverGreen Maven Webapp</name>
 <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

 <properties>
 <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
 <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
 </properties>


 <dependencies>

 <dependency>
  <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
  <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.2</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
  <version>5.2.13.Final</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
  <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
  <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
  <version>42.2.1</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
<groupId>javax</groupId>
<artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
<version>8.0</version>
</dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>


<dependency>
 <groupId>javax.faces</groupId>
 <artifactId>javax.faces-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.2</version>
 <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>




<dependency>
 <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
 <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
 <version>3.2.0</version>
</dependency> 

<dependency>
 <groupId>org.webjars.bower</groupId>
 <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
 <version>3.3.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.webjars.npm</groupId>
  <artifactId>popper.js</artifactId>
  <version>1.14.1</version>
 </dependency>
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
 <artifactId>font-awesome</artifactId>
 <version>5.0.8</version>
</dependency>




</dependencies>


<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>

                    <configuration>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
                                <artifactId>swagger-ui</artifactId>
                                <version>${swagger-ui.version}</version>                                    
                                <type>jar</type>
                                <includes>META-INF/resources/webjars/**/*</includes>
                                < excludes>META-INF/resources/webjars/**/*index.xhtml</excludes>
                                <outputDirectory>EverGreen/target/classes/</outputDirectory>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>  

    </plugins>

     <finalName>EverGreen</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
```

web.xml ...

```
  <web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
  version="3.0">



 <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

 <welcome-file-list>
 <welcome-file>faces/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>



  <servlet>
  <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
   <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
   <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

   <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>



   <servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
     <url-pattern>/javax.faces.resource/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>




</web-app>
```

Thank you ...

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18891768 ?

Comment: nop.its not. i have issue in implementing bootstrap in simple xhtml .

Comment: Is there any one to guide me ?

Comment: did i have to add some entry in face-config.xml ?

Comment: [Steve Casanova](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12671515) posted an [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67012745) saying "This is a good base to start [JSF Bootstrap Starter](https://github.com/EverestConsulting/jsfbootstrapstarter) [https://github.com/EverestConsulting/jsfbootstrapstarter](https://github.com/EverestConsulting/jsfbootstrapstarter)"